# Maven won't associate dependencies with java imports

Tags: java, maven, ambari

I'm trying to build a new Ambari view (Ambari is an open source project by Apache) that will allow users to manage their OneFS cluster at the same time they're managing Hadoop. I'm pretty new to Maven so I'm hoping this problem is trivially easy to fix (it seems like it would be but so far I haven't been able to figure it out).

I have the following imports defined in a .java file:

```
package org.apache.ambari.view;

import java.lang.Integer;                                   // Provides several methods for converting an int to a String and a String to an int.
import java.io.IOException;                                 // Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred.
import java.net.UnknownHostException;                       // Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.
import java.net.URL;                                        // Uniform Resource Locator - a pointer to a "resource" on the World Wide Web.
import java.net.Socket;                                     // An endpoint for communication between two machines.
import java.util.ArrayList;                                 // Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;              // Provides Base64 encoding and decoding as defined by RFC 2045.

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;                          // An entity that can be sent or received with an HTTP message.
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;                    // Static helpers for dealing with HttpEntitys.
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;          // NameValuePair dictionary type.
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;     // Base implementation of HttpClient that also implements Closeable.
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;             // Factory methods for CloseableHttpClient instances.
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;// Extended version of the HttpResponse interface that also extends Closeable.
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;  // An entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs for sending HTTP POST requests.
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;             // An HTTP POST class as defined by section 9.5 of RFC2616

public class Papi {
    private String m_clustername;
    private String m_username;
    private String m_password;
    private String m_url;
    private String m_sessionurl;
    private String m_ipaddress;
    private int m_timeout;
    private int m_responsecode;

    public Papi(String clustername, String username, String password, int port) {
        Socket socket;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(clustername, port);
            m_ipaddress = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
            socket.close();
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR 1: Failed to open session (UnknownHostException)");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR 1: Failed to open session (IOException)");
        }

        m_url = "https://" + m_ipaddress + ":" + Integer.toString(port);
        m_sessionurl = m_url + "/platform" + "/1?describe&list&all";

        m_username = username;
        m_password = password;
        m_responsecode = 0;
    }

    public int GetResponseCode() {
        return m_responsecode;
    }

    public String GetSessionURL() {
        return m_sessionurl;
    }

    // Makes an https POST request to OneFS.
    public String DoPost() throws Exception {
        String response;

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(m_sessionurl);

        ArrayList <BasicNameValuePair> basicNameValuePair = new ArrayList <BasicNameValuePair>();
        basicNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", m_username));
        basicNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", m_password));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(basicNameValuePair));
        CloseableHttpResponse reply = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        try {
            System.out.println(reply.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = reply.getEntity();

            // Parse response body and return as a string.
            response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(response);
            // Dispose entity contents.
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            return response;
        } finally {
            reply.close();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to build the program using `mvn clean package` I get the following errors:

```
root@Martell-AMBARI:/home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view# mvn clean package
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Isilon OneFS View 2.1.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ onefs-view ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/target
[INFO] Deleting /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view (includes = [**/*.pyc], excludes = [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:regex-property (parse-package-version) @ onefs-view ---
[INFO] No match to regex '^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)((\.|-).*)?' found in '2.1.3'. The initial value '2.1.3' is left as-is...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:regex-property (parse-package-release) @ onefs-view ---
[INFO] No match to regex '^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)((\.|-)(([0-9]+)|(SNAPSHOT)|(techwin)).*)?' found in '2.1.3'. The initial value '2.1.3' is left as-is...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ onefs-view ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ onefs-view ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[28,39] package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[30,28] package org.apache.http.util does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[31,31] package org.apache.http.message does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[32,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[33,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[34,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[35,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[37,37] package org.apache.http.client.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[38,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[39,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[41,1] package org.json does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[86,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CloseableHttpClient
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[86,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HttpClients
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[87,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[87,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[89,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[89,84] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[90,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[91,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[93,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UrlEncodedFormEntity
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[94,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CloseableHttpResponse
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[98,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpEntity
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[101,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable EntityUtils
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[104,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable EntityUtils
  location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[INFO] 24 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.002s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 09 01:06:46 PST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project onefs-view: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[28,39] package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[30,28] package org.apache.http.util does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[31,31] package org.apache.http.message does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[32,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[33,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[34,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[35,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[37,37] package org.apache.http.client.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[38,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[39,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[41,1] package org.json does not exist
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[86,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class CloseableHttpClient
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[86,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable HttpClients
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[87,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[87,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[89,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[89,84] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[90,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[91,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicNameValuePair
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[93,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class UrlEncodedFormEntity
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[94,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class CloseableHttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[98,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpEntity
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[101,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable EntityUtils
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] /home/tmunson/ambari/ambari-views/examples/onefs-view/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/view/isilon/Papi.java:[104,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable EntityUtils
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.ambari.view.Papi
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I thought I had included all the necessary dependencies in my pom.xml file for the view, but apparently this is not the correct way to do it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.ambari</groupId>
    <artifactId>ambari-view-examples</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>onefs-view</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Isilon OneFS View</name>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <ambari.dir>${project.parent.parent.parent.basedir}</ambari.dir>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ambari</groupId>
      <artifactId>ambari-views</artifactId>
      <version>[1.7.0.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>rpm</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

So my questions are as follows:

1) Why won't Maven recognize the dependencies I've specified in my pom.xml file?

2) How would I go about making it recognize those dependencies? I'm kinda wondering if I just have the dependencies listed in the wrong place or something, but my understanding of how Maven works is that it will find the dependencies that you've specified in the pom.xml file and then download them and include them in your build. Since I'm including the dependencies but it's not recognizing them, I must be doing that wrong, but I have no clue what the right way to do it would be.

Thanks in advance for any help you all can offer!

Comment: Why have you added the rpm-maven-plugin while you have defined `<packaging>jar</packaging>`? Does not make sense. Furthermore don't use version ranges like `[1.7.0.0,)` use fixed versions for your dependencies.

Comment: Changing version to 2.1.3:
`Failed to execute goal on project onefs-view: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:onefs-view:jar:2.1.3: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.ambari:ambari-views:jar:2.1.3 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.ambari:ambari-views:jar:2.1.3: Failure to find org.apache.ambari:ambari-project:pom:2.1.3 in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss.sonatype.org has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Note: That is after removing nearly all dependency tags and removing the rpm-maven-plugin as you pointed out I should do (it didn't make sense in this pom's context like you said). I'd update the OP to reflect what the pom.xml file looks like now but given that I'm starting to run into other problems maybe I should just make another thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define dependencies within the dependencyManagement section (like you did), those dependencies are not added to the project. They are only configured, so that POMs, which have this POM as parent, don't need to specify the version for a dependency (the dependency version becomes managed by the parent).

So in your case to resolve the problem, just remove the `<dependencyManagement>` and `</dependencyManagement>` tags.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting different errors now about unresolvable dependencies but I'm just glad to see that I'm running into a new problem. Thanks again!